# Wrong sort of RealmSwift

Tags: swift3, realm

This part of code:

```
var posts: Results<Post> {
    get {
        return realm.objects(Post.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "id", ascending: false)
    }
}
```

returns ids like

> 96, 950, 94, 930

My post id is `String`. How to get right sorted objects without making `id Int`.

Comment: use `sorted(by:)` and provide your own SortDescriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, when sorting via a `String` property, Realm automatically sorts it alphabetically, instead of numerical sorting.

Adding the ability to manually sort properties via a block/closure [is on the roadmap](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1265), but there's nothing to announce for it just yet. I recommend you go and '+1' that particular GitHub thread so it can get more priority. :)

The most ideal solution would be to change `id` to an `Int` property if you can. Failing that, njzk2's solution of manually sorting the `Results` into a Swift array 'will' work, but that will page all of the Realm objects into memory at once (causing more overhead), so it's not optimal.